# Equivalent to moveReceived in ElectroServer 5

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am working on a proprietary game project and I am updating legacy code from ActionScript 1 to ActionScript 3. In particular, a lot of the game code from the previous iteration is implemented using the ElectroServer API method MoveReceived. The API provides the following description for this method:

moveReceived:

Availability

Flash Player 6.

Usage

ElectroServer.moveReceived(type,object,from)

Parameters

type Either "public" or "private" (Object)

object An object sent to you (Object)

from The name of the user that sent the move (Object)

Returns

Nothing.

Description

Event fired when a move is received. You can send and receive actual ActionScript objects using sendMove and moveRecieved. This makes creating multiplayer games much simpler.

Example

The following is an example of a move that could be seen in a game where characters can jump and shoot.

```
function moveReceived(type:String, ob:Object, from:String) {
if (type == "private") {
var action:String = ob.action;
    if (action == "shoot") {
    var x:Number = ob.x;
    var y:Number = ob.y;
    var angle:Number = ob.angle;
    var speed:Number = ob.speed;
    createProjectile(x, y, angle, speed);
    } 
    else if (action == "jump") {
    makeOpponentJump();
    }
}
}
es.moveReceived = moveReceived;
```

Does anyone know what the equivalent method from the ActionScript 3 API for ElectroServer 5 would be? I am struggling to find anything that performs an equivalent role. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ElectroServer 5 manual, "Client API at a glance"](http://www.electrotank.com/docs/es5/manual/client_api_at_a_glance.htm) ([link to the entire manual](http://www.electrotank.com/docs/es5/manual/)), you need to employ these:

- `PublicMessageRequest/PublicMessageEvent` - Used for sending messages to a room and receiving them.
- `PrivateMessageRequest/PrivateMessageEvent` - Used for sending messages to one or more users directly, and receiving them.

You might try rewriting `sendMove` as a function that will use appropriate public or private message sending function. The `moveReceived` function code should be split into two branches, one for private, one for public messages.